# Both channels of audio play out of left speaker

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My soundcard is a Creative Labs CA0106 Soundblaster. Every time I reformat my OS I end up only having a single audio output through the left speaker. This audio output includes both the left and the right audio channels. I can usually find a fix online but I have not been able to fix it this time.

I use pulseaudio + alsa. Looking at the channels in pavucontrol or alsamixer the left and right channels are set to equal.

Answer (score 0):

Left my computer on overnight and it fixed itself. I guess all the stuff I tried before somehow actually worked.